# s3 trigger event not working when file uploaded by using node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, triggers, aws-lambda

I am working in node js. I want to execute the trigger when user upload the files to s3. So I created the script in node js which will upload the file to s3 bucket. But s3 event is not fired, however whenever I upload the file to s3 manually then trigger fires.

Please help

Comment: What is the trigger configuration for the Amazon S3 Event? (PUT, POST, "All object create events"?) Have you tried it with "All object create events"?

Comment: Yes I tried with All object create events

Comment: Have you checked IAM policy for the Lambda function?

Comment: Could you also describe, what kind of Policy Actions you are interesting in or used?
- stupid double check - are you sure that script really upload the file.

Answer (score 2):

Since in your questions some things are unclear i.e. which method you are using in `node js` to upload file and what is your configuration in `AWS Lambda` to trigger the event.

I would recommend If you are using  `s3.upload()` then try to use `s3.putObject({})` to upload file in `S3`.

Check the trigger configuration is rightly created in `AWS Lambda`, Make sure the Event type as `PUT` is selected.

[image: AWS Lambda S3 Trigger]

Answer (score 1):

Check for IAM policy for the lambda function. It should have the below permission:

S3:PutBucketNotification